# Problems with Nginx and php5-fpm

Tags: php, nginx

I have the next config for nginx, 
url  **/website/blog/index.php** works but
url  **/website/blog/** doesn't works

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/site;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name site.com;

    rewrite_log on

    #IMPORTANT
    location ~ /.*(\.py|\.ini)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ^~ /website/blog/ {
        rewrite ^.*$ /website/blog/index.php$request_filename last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment this actually looks like it could be basic syntax issues. In future, I would strong suggest running `nginx -t` (without `sudo`) to display configuration errors.

---

I think a try-files is preferred over a rewrite but either way, here's what I use for a Moodle site.

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php/$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ .php($|/) {
            set $script $uri;
            if ($uri ~ "^(.+.php)(/.+)") {
                    set $script $1;
            }
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_index index.php;

            include fastcgi.conf;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$script;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 10m;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 512k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 512k;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 512k;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
            fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_next_upstream error invalid_header timeout http_500;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
```

Unfortunately the exact rewriting rules requires seems to change subtly for each engine, but nginx is popular enough that Googling `nginx url <<engine, eg wordpress>>` will get you some suggestions.

Comment: The problem was that I forget a ; after rewrite_log on

Comment: And after `include fastcgi_params`.